# How to extract results from SOAP response using XQuery in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, soap, xquery

I have a SOAP response with below structure and need to get the all the values for the below tags 1. result , documentNumber , costElementCode .

This is my XML sample :

```
DECLARE @myXML XML = '<commitmentsResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<result xmlns="http://response.cim.its.test.edu.au/">SUCCESS</result>
<value>
<documentNumber xmlns="http://finance.cim.its.test.edu.au/">123456789</documentNumber>
<commitmentLine>
  <lineNumber>2</lineNumber>
  <costElementCode>costElementCode</costElementCode>
  <internalOrderNumber>1000002</internalOrderNumber>
  <costCentreCode>9999</costCentreCode>
  <wbsCode>3000</wbsCode>
  <lineDescription>2 packets of pencils</lineDescription>
  <accountNumber>100000</accountNumber>
  <itemAmount>105.5</itemAmount>
  <fundsDueDate>2015-06-15</fundsDueDate>
</commitmentLine>
<commitmentLine xmlns="http://finance.cim.its.test.edu.au/">
  <lineNumber>2</lineNumber>
  <costElementCode>costElementCode</costElementCode>
  <internalOrderNumber>1000002</internalOrderNumber>
  <costCentreCode>9999</costCentreCode>
  <wbsCode>3000</wbsCode>
  <lineDescription>2 packets of pencils</lineDescription>
  <accountNumber>100000</accountNumber>
  <itemAmount>105.5</itemAmount>
  <fundsDueDate>2015-06-15</fundsDueDate>
 </commitmentLine>
</value>
<value>
<documentNumber  xmlns="http://finance.cim.its.test.edu.au/">12345</documentNumber>
<commitmentLine>
  <lineNumber>2</lineNumber>
  <costElementCode>costElementCode</costElementCode>
  <internalOrderNumber>1000002</internalOrderNumber>
  <costCentreCode>9999</costCentreCode>
  <wbsCode>3000</wbsCode>
  <lineDescription>2 packets of pencils</lineDescription>
  <accountNumber>100000</accountNumber>
  <itemAmount>105.5</itemAmount>
  <fundsDueDate>2015-06-15</fundsDueDate>
</commitmentLine>
<commitmentLine xmlns="http://finance.cim.its.test.edu.au/">
  <lineNumber>2</lineNumber>
  <costElementCode>costElementCode</costElementCode>
  <internalOrderNumber>1000002</internalOrderNumber>
  <costCentreCode>9999</costCentreCode>
  <wbsCode>3000</wbsCode>
  <lineDescription>2 packets of pencils</lineDescription>
  <accountNumber>100000</accountNumber>
  <itemAmount>105.5</itemAmount>
  <fundsDueDate>2015-06-15</fundsDueDate>
</commitmentLine>
 </value>
</commitmentsResponse>'
```

I have tried using the below but only get the first value and not all nodes :

```
DECLARE @DocumentNumber INT  
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (N'http://finance.cim.its.test.edu.au/' as DYN)
SELECT @DocumentNumber = c.value('(DYN:documentNumber)[1]', 'INT')
FROM    @myXML.nodes('/commitmentsResponse/value') t(c)


DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(256) 
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (N'http://response.cim.its.test.edu.au/' as DYN)
SELECT @Result = c.value('(DYN:result)[1]', 'VARCHAR(256)')
FROM    @myXML.nodes('/commitmentsResponse') t(c)


DECLARE @CostElementCode VARCHAR(256)
SELECT @CostElementCode = c.value('(costElementCode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(256)')
FROM    @myXML.nodes('/commitmentsResponse/value/commitmentLine') t(c)


SELECT @Result
SELECT @DocumentNumber
SELECT @CostElementCode
```

Comment: I just suggested an edit. For future reference, you can format something as code by indenting with 4 spaces.

Comment: Yep, looks like you got it. You're welcome!

Comment: I see no xquery here, unless you count the trivial path expressions like `/commitmentsResponse/value` There's some other (SQL-like) technology involved here and you should name it and tag it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` to shred XML data type into multiple rows. This is one example for extracting multiple `costElementCode`s value (implementing for the other elements should be trivial) :

```
SELECT x.value('.[1]', 'VARCHAR(256)') as costElementCode
FROM @myXML.nodes('/commitmentsResponse/value/commitmentLine') t(c)
     OUTER APPLY t.c.nodes('costElementCode') cec(x)
```